# Selected value from dropdownlist has to be tablename from linq query

Tags: asp.net, linq, web-services

I have a problem with my linq query. I want a search field (textbox) with a dropdownlist next to it. When i set the dropdownlist on "ProductID" he has to search only in the table "ProductID", And when i put it on "Productinformation", he has to search in the table "productinformation", i hope somebody understand this?

So what i want is the following query:

```
    var textboxvalue = TextBox1.Text;
            var dropdownsearch = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;    

var Metadata = from m in db.Metadatas
                               join mm in db.Multimedias
                               on m.multimediaID equals mm.multimediaID
                               where (m. {{{Here i want the dropdownsearch}}} .ToString().Contains(textboxvalue) ||
                                      mm. {{{Here i want the dropdownsearch}}} .ToString().Contains(textboxvalue))


                               select new
                               {
                                   mm.ProductID,
                                   mm.filename,
                                   mm.filetype,
                                   mm.filesize
                               };
```

So, how can i get the selected value from the dropdownlist, as a table in the query? Normally you would put m.ProductID into the query, but i want the Selected value in it, something like `m.(Dropdownlist1.Selectedvalue)`... or `m.dropdownsearch`..
Is that possible? And how?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can do this with dynamic linq http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: So, how should this query above look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Metadata = from m in db.Metadatas
               join mm in db.Multimedias
               on m.multimediaID equals mm.multimediaID
               select new { m, mm };

var filtered = Metadata.Where("m." + dropdownsearch + " like '@0'", textboxvalue);
var filtered = Metadata.Where("mm." + dropdownsearch + " like '@0'", textboxvalue);
var result = filtered.Select(f => new
                               {
                                   f.mm.ProductID,
                                   f.mm.filename,
                                   f.mm.filetype,
                                   f.mm.filesize
                               };
```